# JQuery focus() on jQuery-applied anchors works in Chrome and IE, not Firefox

Tags: jquery, dynamic, hash, focus

*Update: This question has been solved, so the buggy Firefox behavior will no longer appear when loading my example webpage*

My webpage has very long passages of text, so I want to make each paragraph its own permalink. To do this, I use jQuery to add an anchor and link to each paragraph after the page loads. This worked perfectly in Chrome. To get this to work in IE I added an explicit jQuery focus() function after applying the anchors. However, this does not work in Firefox if I either load the page for the first time or refresh it (e.g. http://www.readsherlock.com/study.php#p4). The relevant javascript is pasted below.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $("#text p").each(function(i){
        $(this).html('<a name="p' + i + '" href="#p' + i++ + '">' + $(this).html() + '</a>');
    });
    if(location.hash != '') 
        $(location.hash).focus();
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox. 3.5.7, on Snow Leopard. Or, I think it does. It's supposed to jump down to the associated paragraph, correct?

Comment: FYI, Firefox 3.0.16 on Ubuntu doesn't work from clicking the link or hitting F5 once there.  If I just click on the url and hit enter however it does work (sounds like that's what the OP was seeing as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in Firefox 3.0.16

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $("#text p").each(function(i){
        $(this).html('<a name="p' + i + '" href="#p' + i++ + '">' + $(this).html() + '</a>');
    });
    if(location.hash != '') 
        location.hash = location.hash;
});
```

I haven't checked any other browsers so you many need to do both the focus and the reset to trigger all browsers.

Comment: Thanks this worked! Sometimes the simplest answer is the best.